# Beamer - Keep list greyed out, but items within the list invisible

Tags: beamer, itemize, transparency

So say I have a list like:

```
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item This is some text. \uncover<1>{Only 1st slide}
    \item Some more text. \uncover<2>{Only 2nd slide}
\end{itemize}
```

I'm basically wanting the following to occur:
In slide 1 - I want item point 1 to be fully visible, item point 2 to be greyed out, but the "Only 2nd slide" part to be invisible.
In slide 2 - I want the contrary. So item point 2 fully visible, item point 1 greyed out, but the "Only 1st slide" part to be invisible.

I can't find anyway to add this distinction. Everything seems to always either grey everything or nothing. Is there a way to piecewise do this?

Comment: Can you please make a MWE?

Comment: Why are you using `\uncover`, sounds more like a job for `\only`?

Comment: I did not know about \only . That seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something to appear only on certain slides, `\only` is your friend.

```
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item This is some text. \only<1>{Only 1st slide}
    \item Some more text. \only<2>{Only 2nd slide}
\end{itemize}
```